# Bringing the Stack Overflow mission and mindset up to date with contemporary programming practices

Tags: discussion

This is the most problematic aspect of Stack Overflow at the moment for me:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It's problematic for two reasons. The first reason is that yes, that general category of questions can often be very opinionated and have no best answers in some circumstances, such as when there are many libraries for a specific problem or when the problem simply isn't stated precisely.

The second reason is that in fact, good software engineering today is largely about choosing the correct tool or software library in a given situation. So by eliminating all such questions, you encourage poor software engineering choices, such as code-reuse by pasting from Stack Overflow rather than using third party libraries or tools.

In a way, the second issue almost points to a possible conflict of interest between Stack Overflow and good software engineering, since Stack Overflow is about pasting code snippets for code re-use rather than using modules and components.

I will give a more specific case. In [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), we have an example of a fairly advanced software module ecosystem that now has over 277,000 modules. With this reality, solving a particular problem in Node.js *should* be mainly about choosing the correct modules (i.e. software library) first and then in integrating them. Without being able to ask Stack Overflow "given this particular problem, which library/module/components should I use?" we have to consider creating a new site with an entirely different paradigm -- but not because there is anything wrong with the Stack Overflow community or software, simply because of these incorrect policies.

The correct policy is yes, to continue to discourage non-specific questions or voting contests between general categories of tools, but also to amend the policy to differentiate between those situations and specific questions asking for modules or components that apply to a specific set of code or situation.

Comment: Is [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) what you want?

Comment: I didn't know it existed.  Thank you.  I feel strongly that the Stack Overflow policy should be amended as I have stated, since it has a vast community and these issues apply to general programming problems including the majority of questions currently posed to Stack Overflow.  But for now I will try to support the Recommendations community which is better than nothing.

Comment: Besides SR.SE, if you ask "How do I do X under constraints C?" here on SO, some of the answers you get will be "Library L is designed for that and here's how you use it: `code`" (and some will be "You don't need a library for that; just do `code`").  You just can't ask "Is there a library for X?", because those questions tend to attract "I use L and I like it" rather than "here's how you use L to do X".

Comment: Right, the policy is usually enforced that way, but sometimes incorrectly applied when there are very specific constraints given, and main Stack Overflow paradigm is still too focused on code snippets without giving enough weight to integration of pre-existing tested modules/libraries/tools even when those constraints are provided.

Comment: I don't wish to offend here, but your title made me *want* to disagree with you before I even read the rest.  You are making  a sweeping, dramatic statement, instead of clearly stating what you are actually talking about.  It *feels* manipulative and so immediately makes me suspicious.  Perhaps that is just a quirk of mine.

Comment: That's just how serious the problem is.  Of course it's unrealistic for me to think I could fix it.

Comment: I want to do this tool/library selecting, sonds like it's easier than my current 'old style' software development.  Where can I get new tools/libraries?  Is there some kind of plant I can grow?  Are they mined?

Comment: *"we have to consider creating a new site with an entirely different paradigm"* Let me know when you've got that done. I've got some libraries I need to spa... advertise on it.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if such a place existed. But as you recognize yourself, it's outside the scope of Stack Overflow, and around here there is great disbelief that it can work. http://www.slant.co/ is trying to provide that, but I'm not sure how successful it is.

Comment: `Bringing the Stack Overflow mission and mindset up to date with contemporary programming practices` that's just meaningless hyperbole. Finding the right library/tool/platform/API was as relevant in 1999 as it is today. And it's not like the ban on recommendation questions is something ancient and outdated - Stack Overflow used to allow recommendation questions in the olden days (I asked a couple dozen myself), and has since become increasinly narrow in focus. It the result of an *evolution*, not dogma.

Comment: *sometimes incorrectly applied when there are very specific constraints given* - No, it's always correct to flag those questions. There seems to be this idea floating around that if you can write a narrow find/rec request then it's on topic but that's not the case.

Answer (score 18):

> Its problematic for two reasons. The first reason is that yes, that general category of questions can often be very opinionated and have no best answers in some circumstances, such as when there are many libraries for a specific problem or when the problem simply isn't stated precisely.

How is that a reason that the policy of not allowing recommendation questions is problematic? Everything you say there seems to be in support of the policy.

> In a way, the second issue almost points to a possible conflict of interest between Stack Overflow and good software engineering, since Stack Overflow is about pasting code snippets for code re-use rather than using modules and components.

No, you fundamentally misunderstand what Stack Overflow is about. Stack Overflow is about giving complete answers that often include examples. It's about building a repository of programming *knowledge*, not programming snippets. If you just want code you can reuse, you can probably find it on GitHub. If you want a detailed explanation for a real problem you're facing, this is the place.

Answer (score 13):

Here's something that nags me a bit:

> ...[B]y eliminating all such questions, you encourage poor software engineering choices, such as code-reuse by pasting from Stack Overflow rather than using third party libraries or tools.

In all frankness, if your software engineer insists that the *only* way they can solve a problem is to copy and paste their solutions from Stack Overflow, you need a new engineer and **fast**.

And as a counter-point to the Node.JS ecosystem (and it may be tired already), but [things legitimately broke when leftpad left.](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/)  Having a glut of libraries presents the very problem you *believe* Stack Overflow should solve:  which library should I use?

<sup>No, that's not what we should be solving.  You should do the legwork to research which one is best suited for your problem.</sup>

You make a point that software engineering is about picking the right tool for the job, which is *accurate*, but not the whole story.  Often times, the right tool for the job is a tool that doesn't yet exist, and one has to be prepared for that scenario.  It may also be the case that the right tool isn't just *one* tool, but a combination/hybridization of many tools across different platforms that deviate off the marked path.

To bring this together, there's nothing in here that suggests that Stack Overflow will ever be the right place to ask for suggestions on what tool set to use, since the best answer you'll get would be, "it depends".

Answer (score 5):

That "mission and mindset" did not develop because of the state of technology. It developed because people post opinionated answers and spam to these questions.

And people haven't changed since the early days of SO. They've been that way for much longer, and will likely still be that way well into the future.

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is dedicated to providing software recommendations (obviously). It was proposed to fill a void in the system, and it would not really be beneficial to anyone if we broaden the scope of SO. As a smaller site, they can enforce [strict guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305) to keep away spam.

That being said, come to SO with a specific programming problem you need to solve. And if a library is the best way to do so, people will include that in their answer.