# Is it time for SO to reconsider its policy toward library-oriented questions to stay relevant with new trends in programming languages?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

SO is about posting questions about solving programming problems: "how can I do this?". If the solution involves choosing the right library then the poster is out of luck: his question is likely to be reflex-closed by zealous members. [EDIT] This is true, here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22399595/946259).

It was probably OK with "battery included" ecosystems like Java, Python or .NET where a lot of problems can be solved just using the built-in libraries. Unfortunately, there is a trend in programming language design toward ecosystems with lean standard libraries and numerous dependencies through efficient packet managers (Ruby, Node.js, Haskell, Rust, etc...). It means solving a problem usually **starts** with choosing the right library.

SO feels inadequate for those cases. I cannot count the times I was redirected to a closed SO question, with half-baked or out-of-date answers. The closing of the question has usually nothing to do with the relevance or quality of the question, but only with the fact that the solving of the problem relied on selecting the right library to begin with.

I cannot offer more examples or statistics on this issue, but I believe the issue is real and something should be done about that.

What do you think?

Also, I am interested in hearing arguments in favor of keeping the ban on library-oriented questions. Why was it setup in the first place? Is it still relevant? Is it the best way to avoid the problems it was meant to avoid?

I like SO. It would be sad if it became irrelevant.

[EDIT] My question is absolutely NOT a duplicate of "Where can I ask about finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?". It is about raising issues with this site.

[EDIT] My question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322185/946259), which is excellently worded - don't let the down votes fool you. I am not the only one to raise this issue, and I am not surprised the author was a Node developer.

Comment: '*I like SO. It would be sad if it became irrelevant.*' - I really doubt it'd become irrelevant, people will still have issues with vanilla code and generally when a library / framework gets popular a tags is created for it.

Comment: *"If the solution involves choosing the right library then the poster is out of luck: his question is likely to be reflex-closed by zealous members."* - **false**. Questions are rapidly closed when they *ask for library recommendations*. And for good reason, there is no mistaking that is against the rules as it is specifically mentioned. A library recommendation is quite often an answer to a proper problem description, and that is fine. That's the times we live in, software development is largely stringing together existing technology.

Comment: Simply lifting the ban for recommendation questions would be a bad idea unless it is accompanied by a system to keep these questions up-to-date. How should questions be handled where the most up-voted suggestion is not the best library for the task anymore?

Comment: I highly doubt that not making "GIB LIBRARY PLZ"-questions acceptable would make SO irrelevant in any way, shape or form.

Comment: No, it is not.  OP's are notoriously poor at defining their requirements, even when those requirements are such that, when comprehensive enough, they fit into an SO question, (and that is rarely the case).  Choices of library, or whatever, are a system design issue that should be handled by the OP - the only one with access to all the relevant info.

Comment: Example: it's really annoying when some user spends volunteer time in providing a comprehensive and useful answer to the posted question, only to be commented 'oh - boss/customer/prof says I cannot use the XXXX library calls' :(

Comment: lol, ask, and you shall receive: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369945/758133  Underspecified question wastes everyone's time and then, when downvoted, OP moans on meta.   Ths happens all the time when library choices get involved,

Comment: "solving a problem usually starts with choosing the right library" - example? "I cannot offer examples or statistics on this issue - too lazy, sorry " - oh :(

Comment: _[...] his question is likely to be reflex-closed by zealous members_ Skipping rest of question.

Comment: Well, that is accurate.  Q+A lately is getting dominated by people that glue libraries together.  The carpenters that saw their own table legs off to length are getting crowded out.  It is just plain hard to help them.  Most basic issue is that such questions are very, very boring.  A site powered by volunteers can't survive very well on boredom.  They *ought* to ask the library maintainers for help.  But they are bored as well, writing the library was a lot more fun than dealing with the support.  Tricky problem, no easy solutions.

Comment: "It means solving a problem usually starts with choosing the right library.", I see you have an issue with SO, Using "FooBar" Library you can enlarge my So experience and avoid this issue.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the fact that one can recommend a Library, I really think we should not especially because of  "*every reason you used*". When I see the number of docker image with crypto miner, I feel like every lib recommendation should be take with extrem care.

Comment: @AakashM Examples: "how can I read a zip archive?", "how can I parse a JSON stream?", ...

Comment: Today I learned I'm a zealot

Comment: @James_Parsons It depends. Would you have closed the question given as an example?

Comment: @James_Parsons I choose to take "zealot" as a compliment - I like that the community's struggle for quality is seen as uncompromising, just reaffirms that we're doing it right

Comment: @Clive Struggling for quality is good. Enforcing rules just for the sake of it is not. It is then overzealous :-)

Comment: That's quite an assumption, how do you know I'm _enforcing rules just for the sake of it_? You're honestly going to suggest that everyone who doesn't agree with you is doing it _just for the sake of it_? This is coming across as quite arrogant and misinformed, you know

Comment: @ZunTzu What's your basis for the assertion that the rules are not encouraging quality content?  Just *stating* that you think as much doesn't really hold much weight.

Comment: Btw, your example isn't 'this is my problem', it's 'find me a library'. It's a small nitpick, but one of the phrasings is open to questions that aren't a 'shopping list' of items someone wants. If I can code my way to the solution, my answer isn't applicable to 'gimme a library's. But both my code answer and 'hey this nifty library does that, maybe you want to use it' is applicable to 'how do I do this'. (It goes back to Clive's point about title and content of the question)

Comment: @Clive Did I write YOU were enforcing the rules just for the sake of it? Read again.

Comment: @ZunTzu How do you know that whoever you're accusing of following the rules just for the sake of it is in fact doing that, and not doing so because they're actually encouraging quality content?

Comment: @Servy I find that the rule about library-oriented questions prevent good valid questions from being asked. To have quality content, you must have content to begin with.

Comment: I am one of the people who closes questions that ask for library recommendations. Ergo, yes; you wrote that I am enforcing the rules just for the sake of it. It goes without saying that you're wrong, I'm just pointing out the fact that you're insulting people here, me included, by making this suggestion. Do what you will with that information

Comment: @ZunTzu Except that they're *not* valid.  There's literally an exact off-topic reason for those types of questions.  I think you need to do some research on why they're off-topic before you just rail against them.

Comment: @ZunTzu I find that the rule about library-recommendation questions prevent low quality invalid question from being asked.  As library recommendations don't make up the entirety of the content on the site, removing them does not inhibit the ability of quality content to be posted.

Comment: @fbueckert I know the rules. When I wrote "valid", I meant questions which have value with respect to the greater purpose of this site, which is answering programming questions.

Comment: @ZunTzu Their value is minimal, and pose more problems than their value.  The fact that you've found some good answers is the exception, not the rule.  What you don't see are the thousands of deleted questions that SO gets on a regular basis.

Comment: @fbueckert Bad questions should be closed. Good questions should be kept open. I argue that the criteria for closure currently enforced is ill-fitted for dependency-heavy programming languages.

Comment: @ZunTzu So do some research on why we currently close library recommendation questions.  There are incredibly good reasons why we do so.  Once you understand, then come up with arguments as to why we should allow them.  "Code is more modular" isn't a very good one at all.  What we have right now is more a rant than an actual constructive debate on the pros and cons of the reasoning.

Comment: @fbueckert This is not a rant. This is about making SO better. My argument is that nothing interesting can be done with dependency-heavy programming languages without libraries. I can understand that you are not sensitive to this issue, being a VBA and C# programmer. It does not mean my argument is "not a very good one".

Comment: @ZunTzu Modular code has existed since the beginning of programming.  And VBA and C# not being modular?  Pfft.  You have no idea how that works.  But, getting back to the problem at hand: *research the arguments*.  Understand them.  Then come back and argue against *that*.

Comment: @fbueckert "research the arguments. Understand them". Done.

Comment: Awesome.  If you understand them, then you're in a position to argue why they no longer apply, or should be changed.  You could try posting a new question with those arguments, and see how it plays out.

Comment: @ZunTzu: "*My argument is that nothing interesting can be done with dependency-heavy programming languages without libraries.*" That argument is irrelevant. It's not answers which say "there's a library for that" that is the problem. It's questions that ask for libraries, regardless of how "dependency-heavy" the language is.

Comment: @fbueckert Good. No need to post a new question. This one is accurate enough. The rule should not apply to dependency-heavy programming languages (not C# !) because the best way to solve programming problems is often to use a library. Unfortunately, questions with any hint of a reliance on libraries get auto-closed by members who have no expertise on the topic. Can you see how this is a problem for SO?

Comment: I think you need to go do more research, because you're just repeating yourself.

Comment: Don't worry on the downs! Even if your post was downvoted, and you can't even close it, actually this is what the community needs: a more diverse spectrum of opinions. You have the right to publicize what you think, if the community seems not agreeing your idea, but you know that it is a good idea, then it is more a problem of the community as yours.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas This is the theory. In practice, many members feel empowered to close valuable questions - that they don't necessarily understand - because of the existence of this rule, even when the question has started generating high quality articulated answers.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the kind words, Peter. It means a lot. I must say I am quite stunned by the ambiant negativity! :-)

Comment: @ZunTzu: I see no evidence of that. The only example you provided is a question *asking for a library*. That's exactly what is not allowed. Can you show an example of a question which is *not* asking for a library which was closed for this reason?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/4113701/946259
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3785736/946259
https://stackoverflow.com/q/7977945/946259
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34960886/946259
https://stackoverflow.com/q/4113701/946259

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the question @ZunTzu. The very first of those links: _Does anyone know of a node.js email library or an sample contact form script?_

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. Note that in each case the poster was careless in formulating his questions, triggering the closure. Here the shape of the question is more important than its essence, which is sad.

Comment: If you think those are valuable questions worth keeping, what's stopping you from editing them into a form that's acceptable?  Just be aware that you have to preserve intent, so if there's no other problem statement than, "I want a library that does X", it's still off-topic.

Comment: @fbueckert Exactly my point. Those questions were closed for wrong reasons. The rule is counterproductive.

Comment: You're not understanding our point.  If you think they're closed because of the shape, not the essence, *edit the question*.  If you are unable to do so, maybe they're not actually wrongly closed.

Comment: They aren't wrongly closed. The second link is a perfect example of what we want to avoid: a bunch of link-only answers with no explanation of how the library would practically be used to solve a stated problem.

Comment: @fbueckert The questions have all been upvoted many times, therefore they are valuable. You are explaining to me how to game the system given the current rule. The point of my post is to argue for the removal of that same rule and avoid that whole messy situation in the first place.

Comment: No, I'm pointing out that upvotes are *irrelevant*.  There have **always** been popular questions.  Popularity != useful.  Recommendation questions across the SE network are popular.  And they're still off-topic.  Editing the question isn't gaming the system; it's literally using edits what they're meant for.  And I'm sorry, but if you can't even do that, then I don't think you actually have any skin in the game.

Comment: *"The rule should not apply to dependency-heavy programming languages (not C# !)"* Clearly OP is not familiar with Nuget and pains like dependency binding errors

Comment: @fbueckert upvotes are not irrelevant. The questions are only off-topic because they happen to rely on libraries in this particular programming environment. Those libraries are often tiny building blocks, which would be built-in in other languages. You are asking posters to write their questions in a convoluted not natural way to avoid closure by members who have no expertise in the topic.

Comment: @ZunTzu Show them all the positive side of your soul! If you think things can be done better, share it with them! If they attack you, it is their problem! On the top of the command chain is the SE, it is a profit-oriented company and their economical results depend on the visitors and the users of the site! The top government is not evil, they want their fair success by hard work. 1) If we think they are doing something sub-optimally, it is their problem (it is not our job to say them, what they do with their own property). 2) However, they allow us on the meta sites to say, what do we think,

Comment: @ZunTzu how could it be done better, so don't waste this option. The downs of the community does not matter, they are not on the top of the command chain, and they are not interested financially on the success of the SE (company). They want a site which is exactly the same what it always was. | If we think it is sub-optimal in some aspects, of course they won't agree with it, but we are still free to say it on the metas - because the SE allows it.

Comment: @James_Parsons I have been using C# heavily since 2003. .NET is a "battery-included" environment. Nothing like Node.

Comment: No, we're asking posters to *present us with a problem*.  One that's been researched, thought out, and an attempt made to resolve.  A library recommendation question is none of those.  And at this point, I'm done.  You know what you can and should do, and I'm getting tired of repeating those points over and over.

Comment: Well... I have tried to improve things at least. I am amazed at the number of members with NO experience whatsoever in Rust, Node, Haskell, Ruby - according to their profiles - who have strong opinions in favor of enforcing this terrible rule. Have a good night!

Comment: According to your own profile, you have no experience in these either...... so maybe looking at a profile to make that judgement isn't accurate?

Comment: Going ad hominem will not drive your argument any further here. You have mentioned the Rust tag. That one is doing pretty well without explicit requests for crates, they are just often suggested in answers where appropriate.

Comment: related: [Why won't Stack Exchange reconsider the "recommend or find a tool" off-topic tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319285/why-wont-stack-exchange-reconsider-the-recommend-or-find-a-tool-off-topic-tag)

Answer (score 22):

The Q&A format is not the right format for those kind of questions, because answers become outdated as you observed. Even if we didn't close such questions, it would be inevitable.

Now you may argue that SO should build a system specifically for library recommendations. The problem is that such a system would be very opinionated. People would argue endlessly about which library is the best, people would argue whether a library is popular enough to be included in a list, etc.

Imho the best way to find libraries is to Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo what you're looking for, and making a well-weighed decision yourself.

Comment: "answers become outdated as you observed" : this is not specific to library-oriented questions. Languages evolve too. The problem with closed questions is that they stay out-of-date indefinitely.

Comment: I am not asking for a system specifically for library recommendations. I am asking for solutions to programming problems, in the context of programming languages which are not "battery included" and have a package manager.

Comment: "how can I read a zip archive?", "how can I parse a JSON stream?", basic questions really. Would you agree those are legitimate for stackoverflow?

Comment: Valid question titles, yes, but valid questions? No, of course not. Questions need to have context; the practical problem that the OP is facing, the code they're trying, what's expected, what's being produced, error messages, etc, to be useful to this platform. You seem to think that a question asking for a library recommendation, and an answer providing one, mean that the questions must have been the same. Which of course isn't true at all. If the answer to a good, well framed question is "use this library, here's a link, here's a code sample", great. If a question is _find me library_, bad

Comment: @Clive OK, there a good questions and bad questions. Bad questions should be closed. Fair enough. I am actually more interested in the good questions that happen to get closed because of the regulation on library-oriented questions. I am aware of the rules. I would like the rules to be challenged because otherwise SO will soon become a repository for programming lore from 2010.

Comment: There's no evidence to suggest that will happen, only evidence to the contrary. The rule has been in place for years, and the popularity and usefulness of SO has only increased along with it. The rules aren't going to be changed for a single person's baseless hypothetical predictions I'm afraid

Comment: I remember, some years ago I've seen Commodore 64 questions on the SO. Now these questions would be closed as offtopic with some comments suggesting the Retrocomputing SE. I think if, for example, after 30 years, if some of our current technologies will be history, also these posts will be able to be migrated to there. I think, the next candidate for an RC merge will be the https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com .

Comment: outdated is handled by the voting mechansim...there is nothing special in that in these cases.

Answer (score 16):

I disagree with the fundamental premise of this question: that having an SO question that amounts to "does the package manager for my programming language have a library that does X" is useful for programmers. Why?

Because these questions can *already be answered*. Just go to the website for the package manager in question. Pretty much all of them have some form of searching ability. If you need to parse JSON in Python, you [go here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), type "JSON", and you're done.

The package manager's website will *always* be up-to-date. There is nothing SO can provide that is an improvement over their site.

Stack Overflow is useful as a catalog of *problems* with solutions. "Find a library to do X" is not really a problem for most languages that have a centralized package manager.

Comment: So you are prepared to give up on all programming languages with package managers? Node? Rust?

Comment: @ZunTzu: I don't know what you mean by "give up on" them. People can still ask questions about them; not every question in those languages is "is there a library for X". They can even ask questions whose answer happens to be "there's a library that does that for you." But users of *any language* cannot ask "is there a library that does X?" I fail to see how this underserves any particular language.

Comment: in Node, for instance, it is not unusual to import a package that provides a single function with a few lines of code. It is a paradigm shift.

Comment: @ZunTzu: ... so what? I don't see how that changes anything I said. Asking for libraries is not allowed. Asking questions where the answer may be a library is fine (unless it's Too Broad, but that's a different close reason).

Comment: The consequence is that posters have to write their questions in convoluted ways to avoid being closed by members - members who do not necessarily understand the question but who will be triggered by some formulation. How can that be good? (I am looking for an example... stand by)

Comment: @ZunTzu or maybe the posters learn how to do a little research from themselves instead of jumping to SO immediately

Comment: @James_Parsons so the message you want to send them is "SO doesn't want your questions if you use Node, Rust, Haskell, ..." ?

Comment: @ZunTsu Please stop twisting people's words. You are free to ask Question about Node, Rust, Haskell, etc as long as the user has a well defined problem, has made clear attempts, and is clear on all the details on his problem, library recommendations rarely, if ever fit the SO criteria

Comment: @ZunTzu Just because you can't formulate any questions about those topics other than library requests doesn't mean other people are unable to do so.  Feel free to look through some of the well received questions on those topics to see examples of how to ask questions other than library recommendation questions.

Answer (score 9):

> the solving of the problem relied on selecting the right library to begin with.

That is not a reason to close a question.

*"How can I modify Excel files so every Nth cell is formatted with bold text"* is a perfectly valid question (well not literally, but you catch my drift), and answers should definitely refer to any Excel library because otherwise they'd have to include code for parsing Excel files, which you don't want to write.

Off the top of my head I can mention three Excel libraries for .NET, each with their own pros and cons. But that doesn't matter. Each question will result in a different library recommendation (*"I also want to support older, pre-XML Excel files"* will change the applicable libraries). This causes fragmentation and definitely doesn't improve the average question usability for later visitors.

There is never a single best library for all requirements. You'll have to mix and match your requirements with all libraries' functionalities and other conditions.

And what if a library author changes its library to add or remove support for certain functionality, or worse, pulls it or changes the license? This will make answers irrelevant faster than you can blink, and such changes happens on a daily basis.

All this in addition to @Stijn's answer, of which the gist is:

> answers become outdated

It's pretty damn hard to get a newer, better answer rise to the top of a popular question. Stack Overflow is not the place to list libraries for common tasks, for starters because the site's design isn't wide enough to accomodate for the required tables with features.

There are dedicated sites for library comparisons. Use those, and use your Google-fu.

Comment: Interesting answer. "That is not a reason to close a question" : but the question will be closed nevertheless. If you don't close it, someone will.

Comment: "There is never a single best library for all requirements" : that is not specific to library-oriented questions : there is not always a single best solution to all requirements even when no library is involved.

Answer (score 2):

Your question relies on a false premise, because you have badly misunderstood the rule.  You said:

> If the solution involves choosing the right library then the poster is out of luck: his question is likely to be reflex-closed by zealous members.

But this is not true, and your claimed example is not a case where a solution recommends a library, it is a case where the question solicits a library.

It is 100% allowed for a solution -- that is, an answer -- to start with library selection, as long as it is baked up by good reasoning.  But questions have to be focused on the problem, and not a list of library criteria.  Such a question is allowed even if the only way to answer it is using a library (although a few people conclude that a question that attracts answers using libraries a library solicitation, they are mistaken).

Comment: I would like to defend my example. As a C++ expert, would you expect the poster to pretend he didn't know that his problem would require the use of a library? Of course not, it would be ridiculous.

Answer (score -27):

I think

1. Contrary to the current SE policy, yes, software recommendation questions pass well the Q&A format.
2. We can see a working example on the https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.
3. Instead of closing such questions as dupes, they should be migrated to the SoftwareRecs.SE.
4. Unfortunately, doing this would contradict another SE policy: they try to minimize the question migrations with various, sometimes not very rational looking rules. To have a much better SE, also this policy should be eliminated, or at least significantly softened.
5. Currently, the - in my opinion - quite counterproductive rules can be easily circumvented by formulating the questions on a site-conform way: instead "with which library can I do X", we should ask "How can I do X". Often even these questions will be closed, but it is rare that absolutely no relevant info arrives, sometimes in comments.
6. Circumventing the problem that our community tends to vote questions unfairly down, and another problem that meta activity results often mysterious downs to our old, main site questions, it may also be useful to use an alternative account for our questions<sup>1</sup>. This can be done legally on the SE rules.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I don't do this, but if I would be a beginner SE user now, I would do this from the first moment. I find it hilarious that calling somebody, for example, stupid, would result likely a mod intervention. But punishing the meta site users for their activity with main site question downvotes remains below the radar, even if they are enough to deter them for the meta.</sub>

Comment: Regarding point 5 : "Often even these questions will be closed, but it is rare that absolutely no relevant info arrives, sometimes in comments". Exactly! These questions, even closed, have value. Why keep closing them? I am pretty sure most members asking for closure don't even have any expertise in the topic. They are just triggered by the formulation of the question.

Comment: @ZunTzu Probably a part of the SE decision-makers agrees us (this is why the SoftwareRecs SE was created), the other half aren't (probably these are more in control about SO decisions). 2) This is why the SO should have been long split to different sub-sites... it is hilarious that I can cast VtC/VtR votes for .net questions while I never answered any of them. If I review, I need to cast...

Comment: Software Recommendations is moderated even harder than Stack Overflow. For the far majority of recommendation questions asked on Stack Overflow, migrating them to Software Recommendations would just prolong the frustrating process of getting downvoted and closed.

Comment: @S.L.Barth There are always excuses. The SoftwareRecs SE is moderated harder because there is a lot of questions there, but few answers. If the SO and it would have a close synargic relationship, it wouldn't be needed. Btw, hard moderation and counterproductive moderation are different things, I am not always sure which matches better the current SO practice.

Comment: @peterh OK, but I don't think asking for a way to read a zip archive should be viewed as asking for a software recommendation. This is a basic programming problem. It is nothing like pros and cons of Oracle vs MongoDB.

Comment: @ZunTzu Yes. I think such a question would be closed as "no prior research", which may be okay.

Comment: @peterh OK, but if that kind of questions cannot be asked what is the point of this site?

Comment: @peterh IIRC, SoftwareRecs had these strict restrictions to prevent spam and opinionated answers - we already knew the dangers of recommendation questions, and tried to give them a new home while avoiding the pitfalls. You make a good point differentiating between hard moderation and effective moderation. Finding an effective way to make a more flexible recommendation site work... is an extremely tough problem to solve. (But also a worthwhile challenge, if you feel like it!)

Comment: @ZunTzu Enough question can be asked, but the SE has increasing number of concurrents. I think if the elemental rationality doesn't convince the decision-makers, then the rules of the free market will - or they will lose. I feel strong intentions behind to improve, both in the communities and the decision-makers. In 2014, this answer had got 30 downs and an extreme flamewar. Now there is a cultured communication here and it is wonderful. Maybe somewhere in the first half of the 2020s we will see a split SO with easy migrations.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I think the motive behind the SoftwareRecs were that around half of the SE decision-makers agreed that the SE shouldn't give up this content potential, other half tried to "defend" the SO from the "impurity" on all costs. And this was a compromise. I have nothing proof behind that, I only think this might be in the background.

Comment: This answer is a little all over the place. I agree with point #4 but not much else. We already do #5, which is a different kind of question than "what is a good library for X"

Comment: *instead "with which library can I do X", we should ask "How can I do X"* This seems more like a question for Google than StackOverflow

Comment: @James_Parsons I didn't said anything that the question should not pass the other SE requirements (which I consider mainly okay)! Of course examples, clear problem description, users' own research, not too short but also not too long, well-formatting all must have.

Comment: @TylerH #4: thanks, I felt myself always somehow... alone here, with my this opinion :-) #5: yes, and doing this is good. This results that meaningful questions still can be asked, just the OP need to ask correctly.