# Is JUST changing "which library to do ...?" into "how to do ..." already enough to reopen a question closed because of recommending tools before?

Tags: discussion, questions, reopen-closed

For example, a question seen before as example:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37607991/revisions

It seems OP just changed the question part, which rephrased the question body, and other parts almost the same as before.

My question is, while keeping other parts of questions unchanged, is just changing "which library to do ...?" into "how to do ..." already enough to reopen such type of questions? Or it has other criteria to consider reopening (e.g.:background of question) even if the question parts changed?

And another question: is close reason "recommending tools" valid only when OP has clear intent to do so (eg:the question parts mentions "library"), and irrelevant to the question background (e.g.:something like "I tried using library A but it is not working")?

Comment: Library recommendations that are just rephrased to "How to... " questions usually qualify as "too broad". There is no attempt from the OP side to solve the problem, beyond trying to find libraries that do what he needs, so in essence that question still falls under "library recommendation", and currently "too broad" also applies.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Then it should be no problem for you to close the question as being too broad because it is too broad, not merely because it was rephrased from a library recommendation. We close questions based on their current state, not on what they used to be or what we think the OP is trying to do or whatever.

Comment: Normally however it does not have sense to reopen a question just to close with another reason. In this case I would select "Leave closed" and if you are nice you can leave a welcoming comment.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: "*it does not have sense to reopen a question just to close with another reason.*" I didn't say that. I said that you should evaluate the question based on its *present state*. You shouldn't go "oh, it used to be a library recommendation, therefore its current status is too broad and should remain closed." You look at the question and see if it really is too broad, and if it isn't, you vote to reopen it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg It would be great if we could vote to change a close reason while a question is closed, in the cases where it's been closed for the wrong reason. But that's a lot of work for not a very useful payoff so it'll likely never happen.

Comment: @NicolBolas sure I just want to clarify since this question is about reopening and your statement *"Then it should be no problem for you to close the question as being too broad because it is too broad"* could be interpreted as reopen then close.

Comment: instead the buttons in review queue should be interpreted as "Leave closed" <-- for some reason it should not be open (also not original), "Reopen" <-- question should not be closed. If reviewer want to give information to OP what's still wrong with the question they can use comments and I think this is what Dalija wanted to point out with her comment

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess we are in agreement when it comes to judging question by its current state. I never said that just because question was library recommendation question it could not be reworked to question worth reopening. My point was that JUST rephrasing is far from enough - and it USUALLY ends up with question that can be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 36):

You say "JUST" as though that were some trivial change.

Questions of the form "How to do X" are perfectly legitimate on Stack Overflow. We have many of them, and they are highly useful, so long as X is reasonably bounded and scoped for the technologies in question.

Changing "I want a library that does X" into "How do I do X" is not a minor change. In the library seeking case, the only correct answers are libraries that perform X. In the how-to case, valid answers may well involve some library, but a complete answer would also deal with how to *use* the library to accomplish that task. This represents a fundamentally *different* question. And therefore is deserving of reconsideration with regards to closing.

Indeed, this is particularly important for some [newer technologies that are heavily reliant on centralized repositories of thousands of "libraries", some of which only consist of one or two utility functions that do a single, specific thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369946/734069). We don't want to limit peoples answers to just "use this library", but we still want "use this library" to be able to be part of a good answer.

We shouldn't treat the word "library" like it's an automatic disqualification.

> is close reason "recommending tools" valid only when OP has clear intent to do so (eg:the question parts mentions "library"), and irrelevant to the question background (e.g.:something like "I tried using library A but it is not working")?

What libraries someone has available may well be important for solving their problem. Also, if "it is not working" is detailed to some degree, then answerers will know more about the specific reason why that tool didn't work and therefore may be able to explain how to make it work. In either case, such a statement does not mean that they're looking specifically for a library that does that.

Comment: Yes. However, if someone originally wanted a *library* to do a task, they must *already* think that the task is a large task, suggesting that any non library answer is likely to be *too broad*.

Comment: @Raedwald They could be wrong.

Comment: Upvoted for "We shouldn't treat the word "library" like it's an automatic disqualification." I've seen several questions closed like that which should never have been closed.

Comment: @Raedwald: Adding to what Lightness said, we don't close questions because the OP thinks they might be broad. We close questions because they actually *are broad*. Plus, as previously indicated, there are programming environments where "library" does not mean "big, giant thing that does something very complex". Focus on whether the question actually is broad, not on whether the OP may feel that it's broad.

Comment: @rmunn Though in my opinion a question asking for a library is still valid to be placed on hold even if it is able to be 'salvaged' into an on-topic state by changing from 'what library can I use to do X" to "how can I do X". Unfortunately not many people seem to care about trying to save a question that's been placed on hold, and even fewer seem to understand or care about the difference between 'on hold' and 'closed'. In other words, I VTC a lot of questions asking for libraries that could be made on-topic by this kind of change, but I'm always willing to vote to reopen when they're 'fixed'.

Comment: @TylerH: "*even fewer seem to understand or care about the difference between 'on hold' and 'closed'*" That's because there is no difference. It is purely presentation; everything about "on hold" and "closed" is the same mechanically. It's like a variable name; changing the name (everywhere) doesn't affect what the code does.

Comment: @NicolBolas There are actually semantic and system-based differences. In one case, it means this question is not accepting answers while giving the asker the opportunity to edit the question to bring it in line with site rules, *and* the system will also put it in the reopen queue if it's edited during this time. The other case says "it's been several days since this question was closed and it hasn't been edited and/or reopened since then; it's not likely to be edited at this point" and the system doesn't automatically put it in the reopen queue after that point.

Comment: @NicolBolas It also aligns with when most users can vote to delete such content (those between 10k and 20k reputation).

Comment: Comment I wrote before: I've always found this distinction frustrating, any code snippet can be packaged in a library and any library can be unpacked to give the code. If there is a complex problem that has been solved there should be a good tool for it and this would make a good answer. Many SO questions actually have high voted answers recommending tools but the questions must always not ask for this directly apparently

Comment: @Chris_Rands: A question that asks for a tool can only be answered by saying what tool to use. A question that specifies a *problem* can be answered by tools that solve that problem, but *also* by solutions that don't use external tools. See the difference? Furthermore, libraries are usually just a Google/GitHub/centralized-library-repo search away. Whereas solutions to problems are solutions. Also, the answer to a problem statement cannot be *just* a tool; you have to explain how to use the tool to solve the problem. Tools are *part* of the solution, not the solution by itself.